# How does the kernel translate virtual addresses when it's not found in the page table?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, kernel, tlb, page-tables

How does the kernel translate virtual addresses when it's not found in the page table? The page is located on the disk, but how exactly does the kernel know where? (the specific address in the disk)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever a program hits a address and It is not present in page table, CPU exception 14 (Page Fault) interrupts the Kernel.
Control is transferred to Kernel IDT Handler which calls page fault handler.
Page Fault check CR2 register and determine if It needs to

1. Send PF to Program (Segmentation Fault)
2. Allocate Memory
3. Swap page from disk to memory

**Send PF to Program (Segmentation Fault)**: Handler chose this only if program is making an illegal access to memory address.

**Allocate Memory**: This generally happen when program access that region of memory which has been allocated to it (by sbrk) but OS didn't allocate any page frame.

**Swap page from disk to memory**: If OS find, this page is already allocated and It has been swapped to disk (this can be tracked by a bit flag). It quickly ask page file manager (on disk) to retrieve content. when It is retrieved, OS copy it new page frame and make appropriate entries in page table.

Note: Answer is specifically for x86/x86_64 processors.

Comment: Note that, while the overall procedure may be similar on other processors (SPARC, Power, etc.), the details given above (exception 0x14, IDT handler, CR2 register, etc.) are specific to x86/x86_64 processors.

Comment: @twalberg: yeah I forget to mention, Thanks :)

Comment: The last step is highly specific as well. The operating system must keep track of where a process's logical address space is mapped to on disk. Most eunuchs system do that much differently than WIndoze.

Comment: @user3344003 It's completely a general idea; An OS is completely free to make It's implementation look very different, but behavior still remains the same.